# Getting specific Item from local storage with angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to retrieve a specific data from my object stored in local storage using angular. Here is my Object:

```
 {
  "user":{
  "login":"lara",
  "grade":"A"
 },
"profiles":[
{
"profile":"admin",
 "application":"management",
 } 
 ]
  }
```

I want to retrieve profile information (admin) from the list of profiles.
I tried using `localStorage.getItem()`.

Comment: can you post how are you accessing it? what are you putting in `getItem()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setItem in local storage

`const data = { your data object here }`

**SET ITEM**

`localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));`

**GET ITEM**

```
let val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).profiles[0].profile;
console.log({val});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by this..

Use this while storing:

```
var data = {
  "user":{
  "login":"lara",
  "grade":"A"
 },
"profiles":[
{
"profile":"admin",
 "application":"management",
 } 
 ]
  }

localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

while getting:

```
let val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
let profile = val.profiles[0].profile;
```

Comment: in your case it will extract all data, for me i just want profile information "admin"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution

```
let data = {
  "user": {
    "login": "lara",
    "grade": "A"
  },
  "profiles": [
    {
      "profile": "admin",
      "application": "management",
    }
  ]
}
```

**for set data in local storage**

```
localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data));
```

**for getting data from local storage**

```
let val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));

if (val) {
  let adminProfile = val.profiles.find((data) => data.profile == "admin");
  console.log(adminProfile);
}
```